# Which is better for storing non-Gregorian datetime in MySQL? datetime+PHP convert OR varchar OR Unix timestamp as int

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have a table which should have several columns for non-Gregorian datetime (Jalali Calendar). I need to use them in both order and where statements to show the full table content in HTML. Which scenario is led to better performance **by considering both MySQL and PHP execution times**?

1) Converting non-Gregorian datetimes into gregorian using PHP in each read/write and using MySQL datetime.

2) Converting non-Gregorian datetimes into UNIX timestamp using PHP in each read/write and using MySQL int/bigint.

3) Using MySQL varchar.

Comment: Will you need to perform DBMS searches based on your Jalali dates? Is the conversion from datetime to Jalali entirely reversible? How expensive is the conversion operation in php?

Comment: UNIX timestamps don't work correctly for dates before 1970-01-01 Gregorian.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on how much you expect to be using the value within the database, and how you expect to be using it there.

My intuition would suggest doing the database side with standard datetimes and only converting, search criteria provided to queries and displayed dates, on the client/php side when needed. This will allow you to take advantage of the built in MySQL date and datetime functions.

However, as I am not familiar with that calendar, and only skimmed wiki and had *"difficulty in computing the calendar"* stand out to me; so my intuition may be incorrect. It may be you are better off creating a set of stored functions in the database for the Jalali Calendar that mirror the ones provided by MySQL, or it may be much easier to use a full programming language to do the calculations.

You may even want to store the Jalali as something other than a standard date/datetime type or unixtimestamp integer; instead perhaps inventing or finding some implementation of a jalalitimestamp value that could take advantage of the indexing options available in MySQL.